# Cannot find the option "Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies" when publishing Web application Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

when I try to publish a web application project, I am not able to see the option "Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies". I used to see this option on web sites. Can some one advice on this.?

Answer (score 1):

That option is available on Asp.net WEb Stie template. Create an asp.net web site and when you right click on the solution explorer, click publish then a popup window will appear, it contains the option for enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178731%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

- In Visual Web Developer, in the Solution Explorer pane, click your
     Web site project name.
- Click View, and then click Property Pages.
  Alternatively, you can right-click your Web site project name in Solution Explorer and click Property Pages.
- The Property Pages window appears.
  Click the MSBuild Options node.

Comment: There is no MSBuild Optoin tab or I am unable to see that. There is Build tab but it does not contain any option to enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies.

Comment: MsBuild option is available in Web site project not Web application Project as I said in my answer.

Comment: I need to publish a web application, not a web site. I am not sure wheather we can publish by enabling strong naming on precompiled assemblies when publishing Web application Project.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent three part series on how to do this in the aspnet_compiler tool here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228209(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228040.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should include relevant information and use the links only for further reference.

Comment: What I meant is you can use the -keyfile or keycontainer switch to enable strong naming on the command line.